# How to make an Ionic button fit the footer?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In an Ionic (1.3) app I would like to have a footer with only one button fitting the whole width:

```
...
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive">
    <button class="button button-block" ng-click="do()">My Overlapping button :-(</button>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

My issue is that when I set the "button-block" class to the button, it gives the following result: [button out of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcXDU.png)

If I remove the "button-block" class the button fits correctly vertically, except that it does not fill the full application width.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Try inspecting the button, there should have a width property, you can change it using css instead of changing classes.

Comment: Thanks! I could see that there is a 10px top-margin on the button, and that the footer is 44px high. Setting the top-margin to 0 fixed the issue - however I am not fully satisfied with this fix which might not be very resistant to new Ionic releases - One would not have to do things like that normally :-)

Comment: From ionic docs: _"Once you’re familiar with the basics, head over to the API docs for ideas on how to **customize** each component."_ Ionic-framework is made to facilitate your css and html (even javascript) codes, but you will often need to code yourself things like that. After all, not all apps are identically.